# Changing an element's position incrementally using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've just been getting into Javascript, starting with the "dive into a project" approach. My goal right now is to simply get a `div` element to move to the left by 10px, incrementally, for every mouseover. Here's what I have so far:

HTML

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    position:relative;
    width:30%;
    border:1px solid blue;
    height:50px;
}
```

JavaScript

```
document.getElementById("test").onmouseover = function() {mouseOver()};
function mouseOver() {
    document.getElementById("test").style.left = "10px";
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kaikid/mdb6yt4z/)

I understand why this doesn't work - however, I'm not positive how to get it *to* work, and I'm not positive what search queries I should be using.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: jquery animate http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_animate.asp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are missing is, you are not incrementing the value of left property of the element

try this https://jsfiddle.net/mdb6yt4z/1/

```
var left = 10;
document.getElementById("test").onmouseover = function() {mouseOver()};

function mouseOver() {
    console.log(document.getElementById("test").style.left);
    document.getElementById("test").style.left = left+"px";
    left+=10;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  
Now as I understand, the code works as follows:  
1. Increment length set  
2. The element with the ID of "test" calls the function "mouseOver" upon being moused over  
3. The function mouseOver logs the current left (which initially is 0)  
4. The attribute "left" is set to whatever the variable left is currently - in this case, 10. "px" is concatenated for syntax.  
5. 10 is added to left, and it awaits the next mouseover.

Answer (score 2):

You should increment to each function call

```
document.getElementById("test").onmouseover = function() {mouseOver()};
var increment = 10;
function mouseOver() {
    document.getElementById("test").style.left = increment + "px";
    increment += 10;
    alert(increment);
}
```